# How to detect if SpriteNode has NO contact?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to know if my SpriteNode has no contact.

I don't want to know if a contact ends (didendcontact) or begins(didbeginContact)!!!

Is there a way to ask the physicsWorld Object if any intersection is present?

Comment: check out instance method intersectsNode: in doc of >>>> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/intersectsNode:

Comment: I have to correct my self, because this only cares if the frames intersects. Not if the true bitmap overlap.

Comment: Its only work with frames not for irregular shapes and texture. In this condition you need to create your own custom functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This function gives a list of all the bodies that are in contact with the the spriteNode.

```
spriteNode.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()
```